# Images won't appear in Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm using `loadImages()` function to load the images, I then pass the images into an objects that contain a draw function to render the image in the canvas using `ctx.drawImage()`.

However the code has no error, yet nothing appears, can anyone help?

[Github link](https://github.com/Kamzoki/Attack-In-Black/blob/master/JS/CoreGame.js)

Comment: You should post code, not link.

Comment: 1. Add a `console.log('images loaded.') ` to your `loadImages`'s callback to see if the images are available or not. 2. In `loadImages` the `for-in` loop, case is that if `length` is travased before `lvl1_BG` and `level1`, the ones after it won't get image, as you use `break;` to jump out the `for-in`, you should use `continue;`.